# Is there a way to install a lighter version of opencv?

Tags: computer-vision, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, tinyml

Is there a way to install a lighter version of opencv on pi pico? If not, is there a way to install opencv library on an SD card and make pico to fetch those library files from that SD card?

I am trying to record video using a OV7670 camera module and save the video it to SD card. Later I need to upload the video to a custom AWS server. I have the modules to capture images in micropython but can not find any modules or libraries to record video.

Answer (score 1):

No. OpenCV is a huge library, with many moving parts. Even if there is a minimal version of OpenCV, I highly doubt that the 2MB of flash memory of the RP2040 will be enough for your use case. Coupling this alongside the limited number of cores, internal RAM, etc. of the CPU, you will probably end up with nothing. From what I know, you can use TinyML with MicroPython.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenMV](https://openmv.io/) is a project for computer-vision on microcontrollers. It can be used to solve many of the same problems that one would use OpenCV for on a full PC system. OpenMV has drivers for the OV7670 camera, supports video and can be ran on a Raspberry PI Pico RP2040.